# Prepopulating Code in Objective-C Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When you subclass many Cocoa Touch framework classes such as `UIViewController`, the subclass is pre-populated with code such as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this when creating my own subclasses?

For instance, I created a subclass of `UIViewController` called `ParentViewController` which I then subclassed further. It would be nice if I could include key methods with comments that need to be subclassed, almost like built in documentation.

Comment: Yes, try googling "Xcode file templates". One of the links that came up: http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/

Comment: And regarding build in documentation form XCode5 your comments are visible without any additional effort. Check this link for details: http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/comment-docs-in-xcode-5/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Might be more trouble than it's worth but I will definitely read the article and try it out.

Comment: @Igor This is interesting, thanks.